# Is it possible to define mutliple ip address as callback in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 carbon config?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to define mutliple ip address as callback in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 carbon config?
I used WAF as load balancer I want to set three node ip address as call back url in carbon config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define as follows.

```
regexp=(https://myapp.com/callback|https://testapp:8000/callback)
```

Please refer - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-oauth2-openid-connect-single-sign-on/